# How to determine device ID for AMD Ryzen 5 2600 CPU

Tags: cpu, hardware, deviceid

Is working on a Hackintosh mac, and have replaced the CPU.
I'm getting Unknown CPU, and can see that I need to write a CPU Device ID, for the processor.

Can see some threads thats show how to find it for intel, and then use that info.
But can't find any for AMD.
[Unknown CPU Intel](https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/334988-i5-8600k-unknown-cpu/?do=findComment&comment=2628461)

Is there any program, that can show me the device ID on a working windows pc, for the AMD Ryzen 5 or do anyone know the Device ID for the AMD Ryzen 5 - 2600 cpu, like in the link ?

Comment: Macs have Intel processors only in the last ~10 years and macOS supports only Mac hardware, so it's expected that AMD processors are unknown/unhandled... Even though you find a device id for your Ryzen, this CPU can cause stability problems, tricky strange behaviours, not working functions like sleep, power management, etc... My advice is to switch back your motherboard and CPU to Intel if you prefer to use your PC as a Hackintosh.